# What does prototype mean in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I did something like this.

```
var person = function (){
  this.print = function ()
  {
    console.log('person');
  }
}

console.log(person.prototype);
```

This logs `Object{}`, but if I do:

```
person.prototype.print = function () {  
  console.log('person');
}

console.log(person.prototype);
```

Now it prints the entire object and its **proto**